# Does contact picking through Intent require Marshmallow runtime permission?

Tags: android

I am using code of picking contact via Intent, It's working fine without READ_CONTACT permission

```
val contactPickerIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI)
startActivityForResult(contactPickerIntent, RESULT_PICK_CONTACT)
```

Without permission I am able to get Mobile number and Name, so is this fine to use this code? I am confused to use the code without Permission so give me advice, Thanks

Reference Link : [Click Here](https://stackandroid.com/tutorial/contact-picker-using-intent-android-tutorial/), [Click Here](https://www.sinch.com/tutorials/android-contact-picker-tutorial/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Uri` that you get back via `onActivityResult()` without additional permissions. Part of the `ACTION_PICK` protocol grants you permission to work with the content identified by the `Uri` without having to ask for specific permission.

Comment: So, Ok to use my code without additional permission, Thanks for the detailed information.